# How to fix formatting issue when loading page in different tab?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-4.0

I'm having an issue with my website http://www.ben-drury.co.uk/ (I know the content sounds dumb, but it's my first attempt at a portfolio and it's not finished) where the formatting of the text is very peculiar under a specific set of circumstances.

When loading any post or page in Google Chrome, if I remain in the tab for the duration of the loading it looks like the image below, which is perfect and exactly what I want.

[image: Website looking as it should]

However if I start loading the webpage in a new tab and don't instantly navigate to that new tab, or indeed if I refresh the page and navigate away from the tab, when I come back it looks like the image below.

[image: Website not looking as it should]

Interestingly it seems to work absolutely fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox, so initially I thought that it might be an issue with my installation of Google Chrome. However testing it on other computers resulted in the same thing happening, and a variety of different ways of phrasing the issue has turned up very little.

So essentially, how do I fix it for Google Chrome users?

(For those that cannot see the images, the text in the post placed as an example runs outside of the box it should be displayed in and often lines appear over the top of each other around hyper links.)

Update:

I've managed to fix the issue for pages by removing the justified alignment of the text. However I have made said change to the posts as well yet the problem persists for them.

Comment: It's working well in Chrome 44.0.2403.155 m

Comment: Odd, that's the version me and my brother are using and both computers come up with the issue.

Comment: You can try to add the in the css: .entry-content{overflow:auto;}

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a daft question, but where would I put that in terms of WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little more delving into the issue, I came to the conclusion that not only was the idea of web safe fonts actually a load of miss-represented nonsense, but that Google fonts might be the way to go. After installing a plugin for Google fonts onto WordPress and making all my posts use one by default, my problem has been entirely resolved and I can even have justified text on my posts and pages.